# One word for a "very tough task"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need one word to describe a very tough task or a task which one is unwilling to do.

like in the sentence:

> It's very tough to talk politely with the person who is rude to you.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on this, please? Tough in what way? Why are you unwilling to do it?

Comment: like in the sentence..
"Its very tough to talk politely with the person who is rude to u"

Comment: You apparently mean a sense of the word 'tough' drawn from your native language. That way, it is possible to understand your difficulty in explaining better here. See if my answer below helps you.

Comment: Wait are you looking for a word to replace "tough" in your example sentence, or are you looking for a word for "very tough task"? They are completely different...

Comment: like .. Can i use this sentence "its very odious to talk politely with the person who is rude to u" ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The adjective *odious* does not go well standing all on its own. It needs a noun as in *odious task* as suggested by @coleopterist below.

Comment: Not Constructive, in essence polling/lists. -1 research not shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's get downright **crude** here: *It's a **bitch** to talk politely with **a** person who's rude to you*. Typical idiomatic American street talk and locker room lingo. Also heard in classrooms, at sidewalk cafes, and other places where American speakers congregate and jawbone.

Answer (score 9):

If you want alternatives to *tough* as an attributive adjective, you can take your pick from *hard, difficult, irksome, challenging, strenuous, laborious, uphill*. All can be used predicatively as well, except the last.

Answer (score 7):

Arduous is the first word that comes to mind for me.

Comment: I think this is the perfect one.

Answer (score 6):

If it's tough in terms of the scale or effort required,

[Herculean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herculean):

> 1. Of extraordinary difficulty, might, power, size, etc.; of or relating to Hercules in size or strength.
> 2. Requiring a huge amount of work, as a Herculean labour, a Herculean task.

If it's tough in terms of its unsavouriness,

[odious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odious):

> 1. Arousing or meriting strong dislike, aversion, or intense displeasure.

You can find words similar to either sense by [using a thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/odious).

**Edit**:
As per the OP's comment,

> Trying to talk politely with a rude person is an *odious* task

or, using a tamer synonym,

> It is very *challenging* to talk politely to a person who is rude to you.

Comment: like in the sentence.. "Its very tough to talk politely with the person who is rude to u" .. what word can replace "tough"

Comment: @Anupam "odious" can be used aggressively. "Trying to talk politely with a rude person is an _odious_ task" or using a slightly less aggressive synonym, "It is very _challenging_ to talk politely to a person who is rude to you".

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. I need this  sense of sentence.. odious is an appropriate word.. Thank a lot

Comment: So, Can i use this sentence "its very odious to talk politely with the person who is rude to u" ?

Answer (score 5):

We can use "Herculean" word for the a very tough task

```
example we can say "a herculean task"
```

is another word for the same :Extremely difficult

Answer (score 3):

The first word that came to my mind was **ordeal**: a difficult, painful experience. Only one word and it's a noun, not an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

**te·di·ous**/ˈtēdēəs/  (Google)
Adjective:
*Too long, slow, or dull: tiresome or monotonous: "a tedious journey".*
Synonyms:
*tiresome - wearisome - dull - prosy - irksome - weary*

**exasperating** - (thefreedictionary)
*ex·as·per·ate* ( g-z s p -r t ). tr.v. *ex·as·per·at·ed, ex·as·per·at·ing, ex·as·per·ates*.
1. To make very angry or impatient; annoy greatly.

There are a few more words with a meaning on those lines.

Answer (score 1):

After your clarification, I'd suggest *[duty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duty)*. *Duty* usually suggests something that is disagreeable or difficult

> It is your duty as a police officer to be polite to the public.

Although it can be used for something pleasant, this is in usually in a jocular sense

> It is my duty to check the quality of the beer in my local pub

Comment: Thanks Sir.. But "duty" word gives something positive expression.. I want to say like if some person is abusing you and still u have to keep smiling..

Comment: Can i use word "ridiculous" in place of "tough" ? want to give aggressive expression in my sentence

Comment: @Anupam, perhaps you could edit your question to include two or three sentences you are thinking of using; and why you are thinking of using them. We'll get to the nub of the matter a lot faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Labor**. I don't know what OP is looking for exactly, as it's not clear from his question. But based on OP's question title *labor* seems to be the right fit. Here is what the OED has to say:

**1.** work, esp. **hard physical work**: *the price of repairs includes labor and parts.*

Answer (score 1):

If it is not just unpleasant, but hopeless , perhaps [sisyphean](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Sisyphean?q=sisyphean)

> denoting a task that can never be completed.