# Is there a phrase or idiom for a huge task/work/job?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> To repair all these houses is (really) a ______.

I want a phrase/idiom/expression for the blank above which means a huge task, or huge work.

I want the idiom/phrase/expression to mean a task that is very difficult, needs a lot of attention, and a lot of work, and cannot be done fast and quick.

Comment: This is what intensifiers like _very_ and quantifiers like _gigantic_ are for. You can't have a separate word for every degree of hugeness, after all.

Comment: @JohnLawler I just want to give some flavor to my text, otherwise I would simple use ‘huge task’.

Comment: Flavor is determined by the reader, not the writer. Information is more important, and that's supplied by the writer, if at all.

Comment: @Sasan - But there's register to consider.  How slangy, how formal?  Give us the context and a sample sentence showing how it would be used.  Look at some well-received questions in this tag to use as a model.

Comment: a humongous task

Comment: Yes, I imagine it would be with so many comments, but is it done? There's not a creative writing program in the world that doesn't advice writers to be vivid. More vivid! Add some flavoring! A grocery list might be pure information, but Flaubert or Nabokov?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an idiom available that is exactly opposite to cake-walk or child's play?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373768/is-there-an-idiom-available-that-is-exactly-opposite-to-cake-walk-or-childs/373771#373771) Or  [One word for a very tough task/](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80282/one-word-for-a-very-tough-task/80288#80288) Or  [single word adjective for a great or large/expansive task](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370711/single-word-adjective-for-a-great-or-large-expansive-task)

Comment: This question has a different example sentence and a nuance (lengthy _and_ difficult task; not just difficult); and can be filled with a noun or a noun phrase. I don't believe it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> 1: of, relating to, or characteristic of ***Hercules***  [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Herculean#:%7E:text=Any%20job%20or%20task%20that%27s,strength%20is%20therefore%20called%20herculean.)
> ...leading to figurative...
> 2: *a **herculean** task*
> (often not capitalized)
> of extraordinary power, extent, intensity, or difficulty

Hercules was incredibly strong, but he was assigned some incredibly difficult tasks - which you can google yourself if you're interested; you don't need to know the details to understand the idiomatic usage.

---

There's also (again, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Sisyphean))...

> ***Sisyphean***
> of, relating to, or suggestive of the labors of Sisyphus
> specifically *requiring continual and often ineffective effort*
> ***a Sisyphean task***

Where Sisyphus was assigned a task that was effectively ***impossible** [to complete]*. And if you don't want usages derived from Greek myths, we Brits can now use [painting the Forth Bridge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/like_painting_the_Forth_Bridge#:%7E:text=all%20over%20again.-,Prepositional%20phrase,in%20vain%20because%20of%20this.) (for a "never-ending" task; by the time you've painted it all the way from one end to the other, the end you started at needs *repainting*).

Answer (score 1):

**Long haul** is an idiomatic expression used for a lengthy and difficult task/effort/work/process.

> A prolonged and difficult effort or task. - *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/long_haul)*
>
> If you say that a task or a journey is a long haul, you mean that it takes a long time and a lot of effort. - *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/long-haul)*

**Ordeal** is used colloquially as a hyperbole.

> A very unpleasant and prolonged experience. - *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ordeal)*

> *To repair all these houses is an ordeal.*

**Ball-breaker** (also *ball-buster*) is a US slang word that you can consider also.

> A demanding and punishing task or situation. - *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ball-breaker)*
>
> A difficult, boring, or exasperating job, problem, or situation. - [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14943#eid28758849) 
> *You can't believe what I've been through. And then today, a real ball-breaker.*

Answer (score 0):

> [a tough/hard row to hoe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20tough%2Fhard%20row%20to%20hoe)
>
> something that is difficult to do or deal with.
>
> Example:
> I am considering
> becoming a doctor, but I know that it's a tough row to hoe.

Answer (score 0):

> According to [Dictionary - gargantuan](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gargantuan):
>
> > a gargantuan task
> >
> > gigantic; enormous; colossal